# Tensorflow software upgrade

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have taken the following steps to install TensorFlow in an Anaconda environment:

1. I have installed the 64-bit version of Anaconda for Windows.

I am currently using the Anaconda version of python for PyCharm

2. I created a conda environment named tensorflow by invoking the following command:

   C:> conda create -n tensorflow

Activate the conda environment by issuing the following command:

```
C:> activate tensorflow
```

(tensorflow)C:>  # Your prompt should change

Issue the appropriate command to install TensorFlow inside your conda environment. 
To install the CPU-only version of TensorFlow, enter the following command:

```
(tensorflow)C:> 
pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/cpu/tensorflow-1.0.1-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl
```

## The line listed above is what I currently have.

Note: Now I would like to upgrade to this version of tensorflow.

```
pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/cpu/tensorflow-1.1.0-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl
```

Question: Do I need to uninstall the previous version 
https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/cpu/tensorflow-1.0.1-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl
OR 
can I go ahead and execute

```
pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/cpu/tensorflow-1.1.0-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl
```

I believe I can upgrade because of the upgrade flag in the pip command.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can,I've done with it before.

```
pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/cpu/tensorflow-1.1.0-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl
```

Answer (score 0):

You can completely uninstall by using below command

```
sudo pip uninstall protobuf
sudo pip uninstall tensorflow
```

But you are not required to if you want to upgrade it by below command.

```
sudo pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-0.8.0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl
```

When you are using conda, this one is safe way to uninstall tensorflow include environment.

```
python3 -m pip uninstall protobuf    
python3 -m pip uninstall tensorflow-gpu
```